# How to get context-sensitive help in MS Visual Studio Pro 2012?

Tags: visual-studio

According to the book I have and what online info I can find, to get context-sensitive help while editing source I simply highlight a term and press F1.

However, F1, when pressed, inevitably brings up "Windows Help and Support", and it denies all knowledge of anything related to Visual Studio or the data types contained therein.

I have most of the .NET documentation installed.  But finding info on a particular term going through the Help Viewer is very awkward.

## Never Mind!

I'm using an unfamiliar laptop and it has the `fn` key reversed -- you only get function  keys if you hold the `fn` key as you press.  Otherwise the F1 key maps to "?", the Windows Help function.  Grumble.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, it turned out to be an unfamiliar laptop.  This one (Sony) has the F keys black and the special functions blue, and you press and hold `Fn` to get the special functions.  But on the one where VS is installed (an HP) the `Fn` key is kind of "sticky" and so pressing an F key will sometimes result in the Fx keystroke and sometimes result in the "special function" keystroke, in a relatively unpredictable fashion.

Now that I know this I know to hit the `Fn` key and try again if "Windows Help and Support" pops up.

Comment: Thank you. I've just realised that my laptop is doing the exact same thing. I'm not sure why your question has been downvoted but it helped me.